How pathological can an unbounded function with a closed graph be?
This question has been inspired by the answers and comments received on this sister question.
Let $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be a non-degenerate closed (but not necessarily bounded) interval. Suppose that $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is a function with a closed graph. This means that the set $\{(x,f(x))\,|\,x\in I\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
It is clear to me (see, for example, here) that if $f$ is also assumed to be bounded, then it must be continuous. However, continuity is not guaranteed without boundedness. For example, if $I=[0,1]$ (a compact interval) and $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{1-x}&\text{if $x\in[0,1)$,}\\
0&\text{if $x=1$,}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
then $f$ has a closed graph but it is discontinuous at $x=1$. More complicated examples can be constructed with a greater number of discontinuities.
My question is twofold:

Is there a characterization of how pathological $f$ can be? (Admittedly, this question is vague, so interpret it freely.)

In particular, I conjecture (but could neither prove nor come up with a counterexample) that $f$ must be of Baire class 1—that is, it must be a pointwise limit of continuous functions. Is this conjecture true?


Any guidance regarding these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Does someone know an example of such an $f$ with uncountably many discontinuities? One example with countably many discontinuities is $f(x) = \dfrac1{(\lfloor1/x\rfloor+1)x-1}$, or more precisely, the function defined on $[0,1]$ by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac1{(n+1)x-1}, & \text{if } \dfrac1{n+1}<x\le\dfrac1n \text{ for a positive integer }n, \
\text{(anything)},& \text{if } x=0.
\end{cases}
$$

@GregMartin This paper indicates that the set of discontinuities must be closed and nowhere dense. Of course, it does not imply anything as to countability, and it seems to me to be weaker than what’s required to guarantee the Baire-class-1 property.

@GregMartin Another update: That same paper claims that for any closed and nowhere dense subset of the real line (in particular, any lean or fat Cantor set), there exists a real-valued function with a closed graph whose set of discontinuities is precisely the set in question. The construction is structurally similar to that of your example. This seems to settle the question of the possibility of uncountably many discontinuities (constituting possibly even a set of full measure) in the affirmative. I still don’t know if such counterexamples are consistent with the Baire-class-1 property.

Correction: In the previous comment, “full measure” should have been “almost full measure”.

I now have a proof showing that any function satisfying the premises in the above question must be of Baire class 1 (a pointwise limit of continuous functions). I would greatly appreciate any feedback on this proof.
Let $G_f\subseteq I\times\mathbb R$ denote the graph of $f$. Let $C_f\subseteq I$ and $D_f\subseteq I$ denote the sets of points at which $f$ is continuous and discontinuous, respectively. By Theorem 24.10 in Kechris (1995, p. 192), it will be sufficient to show that the pre-image $f^{-1}(U)$ is $F_{\sigma}$ (the countable union of closed sets) for any open $U\subseteq\mathbb R$.
UPDATE: The rest of the proof is unnecessarily complicated (but I’m gonna keep it for my records). Scroll to the bottom of this answer for a much simpler proof.
According to Theorem 2 in Baggs (1974, p. 440), $D_f$ is closed (and nowhere dense, but this latter property will not be needed). Consequently, $C_f$ is open (and dense). Let $U\subseteq\mathbb R$ be open. One then has that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(U)=(f|_{C_f})^{-1}(U)\,\cup\,(f|_{D_f})^{-1}(U).
\end{align*}
Since the function $f|_{C_f}$ restricted to $C_f$ is continuous, it follows that $(f|_{C_f})^{-1}(U)$ is relatively open in $C_f$ and also open in $I$ given that $C_f$ itself is open. Since open sets in a Euclidean space are $F_{\sigma}$, it follows that $(f|_{C_f})^{-1}(U)$ is $F_{\sigma}$.
The proof will be complete upon showing that $(f|_{D_f})^{-1}(U)$ is also $F_{\sigma}$. To this end, represent $U$ (which is open and hence $F_{\sigma}$) as a countable union $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$, where $C_n\subseteq\mathbb R$ is closed for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Since
\begin{align*}
(f|_{D_f})^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(f|_{D_f})^{-1}(C_n)
\end{align*}
and the union is countable, it is sufficient to prove that $(f|_{D_f})^{-1}(C_n)$ is $F_{\sigma}$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.
Fix $n\in\mathbb N$ and note that
\begin{align*}
(f|_{D_f})^{-1}(C_n)=\{x\in D_f\,|\,f(x)\in C_n\}=\pi_1\left(G_f\cap(D_f\times C_n)\right),
\end{align*}
where $\pi_1(\cdot)$ denotes the projection to the axis of the first coordinate. Since $G_f$ and $D_f\times C_n$ are closed, so is their intersection. And the projection of a closed set in the plane is $\sigma$-compact (see here) and hence also $F_{\sigma}$.

Here is a simplification of the above proof:
Let $U\subseteq\mathbb R$ be open. Represent $U$ (which is an open set in a Euclidean space and hence $F_{\sigma}$) as a countable union $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$, where $C_n\subseteq\mathbb R$ is closed for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Since
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(C_n)
\end{align*}
and the union is countable, it is sufficient to prove that $f^{-1}(C_n)$ is $F_{\sigma}$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Fix $n\in\mathbb N$ and note that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(C_n)=\pi_1\left(G_f\cap(I\times C_n)\right),
\end{align*}
where $\pi_1(\cdot)$ denotes the projection to the axis of the first coordinate. Since $G_f$ and $I\times C_n$ are closed, so is their intersection. And the projection of a closed set in the plane is $\sigma$-compact (see here) and hence also $F_{\sigma}$.
